# How to update data from excel table into SQL based database?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have an excel table with name, value and Date columns. I want to put these values and dates in database. I managed to create connection with Database with the following code. The strategy in this code is to go inside database with the name and then in next step go to underliyng table with the uniqueid of this name. Then with this id update values and date in underlying table. Problem is to link excel table so that should take value and dates from this excel table of the given name.

```
Name               Value           Date 

12345_ABC_DefGeh   12345678        01.11.2018
```

......so on around 15 values.

```vb
Sub fixing()    
      Dim pReference As String  
      Dim pFixingValue As Double
      Dim pFixingdate As Date
      Dim pReferenceUnderlying As String

       Dim Con As ADODB.Connection
       Dim Q As New AblSQLQuery
       Dim SQL As String

      Dim uniqueid As Long  ' uniqueid is the unique code of this instrument
      Dim uniqueidUnderlying As Long  
      Dim QuoteType As Long
      Dim Numero As Long
      Dim Stmt As ADODB.Recordset
      Dim bInsert As Boolean
      Dim Ins As SR2COM.Instrument
      Dim InsUnderlying As SR2COM.Instrument
      Dim Ins2 As SR2COM.Instrument
       '
     If isDeveloper() = True Then
         pReference = "12345_ABC_DefGeh"
     End If
     '
     Engine.Risque.Initialise
     Pref.GetUserID Operator, OperatorGroup

     Set Con = Engine.xvz.ConnectADO
     ' get uniqueid and set instrument

     uniqueid = Engine.Instrument(pReference).Code
     Set Ins = Engine.Instrument(uniqueid)

      If pReferenceUnderlying <> vbNullString Then
         UniqueidUnderlying = Engine.Instrument(pReferenceUnderlying).Code
      End If

      ' select latest fixing entry

           SQL = "SELECT *" & _
            " FROM ABV_local_fixings a" & _
           " WHERE Code = " & uniqueid

     If SicovamUnderlying <> 0 Then
         SQL = SQL & _
             " AND underlying = " & uniqueUnderlying
     End If

    SQL = SQL & _
             " AND observation = (SELECT MAX(observation)" & _
                                  " FROM ABV_local_fixings b" & _
                                 " WHERE b.code = a.code"
     If UniqueidUnderlying <> 0 Then
         SQL = SQL & _
                                   " AND b.underlying = a.underlying"
     End If
     SQL = SQL & _
                                 ")" & _
           " ORDER BY numero DESC"

     Set Stmt = Con.Execute(SQL)
 '    End If
     Numero = Stmt!Numero
     QuoteType = Stmt!QuoteType
     UniqueidUnderlying = Stmt!Underlying
     Set InsUnderlying = Engine.Instrument(UniqueidUnderlying)

    If pReferenceUnderlying = vbNullString Then
         pReferenceUnderlying = InsUnderlying.Reference
     End If

check if insert or update

     SQL = "SELECT *" & _
            " FROM ABV_local_fixings a" & _
           " WHERE Code = " & uniqueid

    If UniqueidUnderlying <> 0 Then
         SQL = SQL & _
             " AND underlying = " & UniqueidUnderlying
     End If

    SQL = SQL & _
             " AND observation = TO_DATE('" & Format(pFixingdate, "ddmmyyyy") & "', 'DDMMYYYY')"

     Set Stmt = Con.Execute(SQL)

    If Stmt.EOF Then
         bInsert = True
     End If

     ' insert/update fixing

       If bInsert = True Then
         SQL = "INSERT INTO ABV_local_fixings" & _
                         " (numero, code, observation, underlying, value,  quotetype)" & _
                  " VALUES (" & Numero + 1 & _
                          "," & Uniqueid & _
                          ",TO_DATE('" & Format(pFixingdate, "ddmmyyyy")   & "', 'DDMMYYYY')" & _
                          "," & UniqueidUnderlying & _
                          "," & pFixingValue & _
                          "," & QuoteType & _
                          ")"
     Else
         SQL = "UPDATE ABV_local_fixings" & _
                 " SET value = " & pFixingValue & _
               " WHERE numero = " & Numero & _
                 " AND code = " & Uniqueid & _
                 " AND observation = TO_DATE('" & Format(pFixingdate, "ddmmyyyy") & "', 'DDMMYYYY')" & _
                 " AND underlying =" & UniqueidUnderlying
     End If  

 End Sub>
```

The problem is to connect excel table i took this code from similar previous project. But it perfectly work to enter into database and reach to the underlying table. I am sure small modifications would be enough, i spent too much time but still unable to solve the problem.

Comment: Mak,
I agree with Jorge, as you connected to DB, you need only to execute the SQL command in your object.

Set Stmt = Con.Execute(SQL)

Answer (score 0):

use the

```
insert into table_name values ()
```

it's only 15 rows that you need to insert. Plus, you can automate that insertion from excel with a bit of copy/paste of string values.

Comment: no not exactly 15 its supposed to be 15 every day i receive different number of emails so i want to update all of them.